# Creating a python lmfit Model with arbitrary number of parameters

Tags: python, curve-fitting, polynomials, lmfit

Is there a way to construct a an lmfit Model based on a function with an arbitrary number of dependent variables?  For example:

```
from lmfit import Model

def my_poly(x, *params):
  func = 0
  for i in range(len(params)):
    func+= params[i]*z**i
  return func

#note: below does not work
my_model = Model(my_poly, independent_vars = ['x'], param_names = ['A','B','C'])
```

Something similar to the above would be wonderful if I am interested in a polynomial series and want to test the performance as the series grows or shrinks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Model()` uses function argument names to build parameter names, using `*params` won't work easily (how would one know to call them `A`, `B`, `C`, and not `coeff0`, `coeff1`, `coeff2`, or something else?).

I don't know that a truly *arbitrary number* could be supported, but it should be possible to do a very large number.   The Polynomial Model (see http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html#polynomialmodel and https://github.com/lmfit/lmfit-py/blob/master/lmfit/models.py#L126 for implementation) supports up to 7 coefficients.   It should be no problem to extend that to a much larger number.  It might easily lead to computational problems, but I think that is what you are expecting to explore.

If you're willing to make a small change, it *is* be possible to do something like you're looking for.  This uses keyword arguments instead of positional arguments, and relies on parameter name order (that is with `sort`) to indicate which coefficient goes with what exponent, rather than order of the positional arguments.   This might be close to what you're looking for:

```python
import numpy as np

from lmfit import Model, Parameters

def my_poly(x, **params):
    val= 0.0
    parnames = sorted(params.keys())
    for i, pname in enumerate(parnames):
        val += params[pname]*x**i
    return val

my_model = Model(my_poly)

# Parameter names and starting values
params = Parameters()
params.add('C00', value=-10)
params.add('C01', value=  5)
params.add('C02', value=  1)
params.add('C03', value=  0)
params.add('C04', value=  0)

x = np.linspace(-20, 20, 101)
y = -30.4 + 7.8*x - 0.5*x*x + 0.03 * x**3 + 0.009*x**4
y = y + np.random.normal(size=len(y), scale=0.2)

out = my_model.fit(y, params, x=x)
print(out.fit_report())
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Excellent! I've explored the built-in polynomial model, but it is difficult to use in my actual analysis.  However, you suggestion regard kwargs instead of args is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Whille were are on this topic of arbitrary number of parameters, would it be possible to say fit an arbitrary number of gaussians ? i.e where the number of gaussian models is variable ? of course with limits say from 2 - 10 max ? Thanks in advance.